# Ran Sudo chmod 755 -R /. Is My Data Gone?

Tags: mongodb, debian, chmod

So I (I know, I am an idiot) ran

```
Sudo chmod 755 -R /
```

Intending

```
Sudo chmod 755 -R ./
```

I have read the other posts here and I understand why reinstalling is my best option. I have already reinstalled and reconstructed the environment on a different VM, so the server is up and running again.
My question is: I had a mongodb instance running on this server. Is my data recoverable? I haven't been able to log in, or connect though SSH. I am running this VM through VSphere, and it runs Debian.

EDIT: adding that the approach of executing:

```
mongodump --host HOST --db DB --out OUTFILE
```

returns the following error message:

```
Failed: Error connecting to db servers: no reachable servers.
```

Comment: You will have to track down the permission problems regarding the mongodb server to start it again and dump the database **or** maybe just copy the datadir over, fix the permissions according to your recreated env and try to start the new mongodb server.

Comment: Dang son, you don messed up